# React JSX error trying to use Less Than Symbol

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a simple button with an arrow point to the left, so I figured I would use the "<". However when I do

```
<button><</button>
```

am I getting an unexpected token error I guess because it thinks I am starting a new element rather than just wanting the < to be the text in the button. Is there anyway around this? Replacing < with "test" compiles and works fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the HTML code for less than.

```
    <button>&lt;</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

HTML entities work; alternatively, you can use braces to interpolate that string in plain JS:

```html
<button>{"<"}</button>
```

It’s worth noting that in cases where the button text doesn’t tell the user what it does, you should include an [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) attribute with a description:

```html
<button aria-label="back">{"<"}</button>
```

This makes your site more accessible by allowing folks with screen readers or similar to easily understand how to interact with it.

Comment: The best answer, far more convenient than playing around with HTML entities. Unless there are some negative consequences I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 7):

Use HTML entities (https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

`&lt;` for less than.